# Flutter: how to force Android debugger to just print Flutter code?

Tags: flutter, debugging, printing, console

[image]

I get this logs and hard to check `print()` on console. How can I minimize these logs popping up every second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is by filtering the logs according to your print statements,
all you have to do is to add a unique keyword of your own in the print statement followed by the flutter code to print as follow:

```
print('DebugPrintStatement: $FLUTTER_CODE_TO_PRINT');
```

then by pressing Ctrl + F in the debug console and enter your unique keyword (ex: DebugPrintStatement)

and just make sure that you look at the logs from debug console tab not Logcat tab!